# Is there a standard for the "transaction type"?

Tags: accounting, budget, bookkeeping

After designing and using my personal bookkeeping system for quite some time, I realized that it lacks one column: what "type" of transaction it is.

I have made it a `smallint` called `type` with these possible values:

```
null    Unspecified.
1   Purchase of physical object.
2   Purchase of service in real life.
3   Purchase of service existing entirely electronically/abstractly/on the Internet.
4   Purchase of currency.
... [Probably many more...]
```

Is this standardized/established somehow?

I already have a separate "category" column which is more in the sense of "rent", "electronics", "Bitcoin", "food", "correction", "income", etc. To me, it seems like these should not be combined into one column, because they refer to slightly different "properties" of the transaction, and I want to be able to list all "electronics" transactions without having to specify whether it was bought as a physical thing from a store or "rented in the cloud", etc.

I'm asking because whenever I design my own system, I tend to eventually have to change it around a million times or even scrap it altogether when it eventually turns out (by sheer chance) that there is already a "standard" way of doing it which has had a million thought-hours put into it before I ever was born.

Comment: This is more of a programming question than a personal finance question and probably belongs on one of the other SE sites.

Comment: Possibly, durable product, non-durable product, trading product, depreciating service (like renovation), and regular service.

Comment: @JohnFx This question is about creating a system for personal accounting; the programming aspect is merely tangential. Because it is about accounting for personal finance, it is on-topic here.

Answer (score 4):

When it comes to bookkeeping for your personal finances, there are no standards. You are free to use whatever system works for you.

You want to provide yourself with enough data to be able to look at your history and gain insight for making desired changes in your behavior, but you also want to keep it simple enough to ensure that it is not too much work to sustain using it.

For some people, the “type” field you describe would not be necessary.  For example, if you watch a movie for entertainment, does it matter if you go to a movie theater (“service in real life”), buy a DVD (“physical object”), or stream it online (“service existing entirely electronically”)?  Some people would say, no, it doesn’t matter; entertainment dollars are entertainment dollars. But other people (yourself, perhaps) may see the value in analyzing their spending in this way.

I can see some value in this. Some might have a goal of spending less time online and more time socializing with people physically. Others may want to try to maximize their virtual purchases to reduce their clutter and space requirements. Both groups might find it useful to be able to look at whether their purchases were physical or virtual.

The choice of whether to add this field is up to you. If you think that the data would be useful to you in the future to accomplish your goals and you don’t think it will be too burdensome to have to enter it with every transaction, then go for it. It is important to remember, however, that it is okay to pick a direction now and change it later. No matter which one you choose, you will learn later if the data is useful or if it is too difficult to maintain, and you can always change your system later.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you allow multiple tags to describe transactions, then the level to which you organize the transactions is not limited by some pre-set values that you'll have to change around.

Having some general top-level categories makes sense, but as you've observed it doesn't allow you to answer some of the questions you might have about your spending. Keep the top-level categories and also include the tagging option.

As an example, maybe you're a big board game fan and bought 18 last year, 4 of them are in your 'Gift' category and another 14 are in your 'Discretionary' category, but they could all also have a 'board game' tag so you can know how much you spend on board games specifically if you don't want to introduce a 'Board Game' category as a budget item on its own. Similarly maybe the 4 you gifted include a 2nd tag that's the name of the person you purchased them for, then you could easily refer to past purchases for an individual. One nice thing about this approach is that there's no need for sweeping re-categorization if you change your mind about the value of certain tags.

Most of the time 'Insurance' is all the detail I care about for budgeting purposes, but when it comes time to review policies having some tags could be helpful as you might want to know how much you spent per year on auto insurance in general, or for a specific vehicle.

The important thing will be that any cumulative reports are aggregated based on the general category/first tag, or that your reports otherwise account for multiple tags/tag overlap so that you do not double-count transactions. You could still report in aggregate based on just the top-level category, the first tag for each transaction, or a list of all tags for each transaction without double-counting, it's an incredibly flexible approach.

This is the approach that I use for photo management and have always wished there was a budgeting/spend-tracking application that offered similar (there might be now, I haven't checked in a while). If you go this route, I'd suggest you don't add tags for attributes that are already known, for example you have a transaction date, so there's no value in adding a '2021' tag.

Comment: +1 for using tags for this. They provide the most flexibility for the future.